# Enhanced "ls" with git status information?

Tags: git

Is there either an existing command, or some trick or script that allows me to show the status of the files shown in "ls"?

Something like the following:

```
$ git ls status #Command could be anything `lsg` is fine too, whatever.

app           contents modified
autotest      up-to-date
config        up-to-date
config.ru     staged
db            contents modified
doc           contents modified
Gemfile       modified
Gemfile.lock  modified
lib           up-to-date
log           up-to-date
public        up-to-date
Rakefile      up-to-date
README        up-to-date
script        up-to-date
spec          up-to-date
tmp           up-to-date
vendor        contents modidified
test.tmp      removed
```

In any way: having the git status information available in a directory listing.

Comment: What would you argue is the benefit of this format over `git status`?

Comment: @Nate: It offers a better birdseye, IMO. Especially usefull if many files were changed. But also to see the changes in context of the entire dir-listing is usefull.

Comment: The closest is probably `git status -s`, but it will not report anything other than modifications

Comment: `-uno` to omit output of untracked files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the Git status [short format](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-status.html#_short_format) information, here's a Bash script that uses Awk and the `column` command to give you customized status output.

```
#!/bin/bash
git status --porcelain | \
    awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}
{
    xstat = substr($0, 1, 1);
    ystat = substr($0, 2, 1);
    f = substr($0, 4);
    ri = index(f, " -> ");
    if (ri > 0) f = substr(f, 1, ri);
    if (xstat == " " && ystat ~ "M|D") stat = "not updated";
    else if (xstat == "M" && ystat ~ " |M|D") stat = "updated in index";
    else if (xstat == "A" && ystat ~ " |M|D") stat = "added to index";
    else if (xstat == "D" && ystat ~ " |M") stat = "deleted from index";
    else if (xstat == "R" && ystat ~ " |M|D") stat = "renamed in index";
    else if (xstat == "C" && ystat ~ " |M|D") stat = "copied in index";
    else if (xstat ~ "M|A|R|C" && ystat == " ") stat = "index and work tree matches";
    else if (xstat ~ " |M|A|R|C" && ystat == "M") stat = "work tree changed since index";
    else if (xstat ~ " |M|A|R|C" && ystat == "D") stat = "deleted in work tree";
    else if (xstat == "D" && ystat == "D") stat = "unmerged, both deleted";
    else if (xstat == "A" && ystat == "U") stat = "unmerged, added by us";
    else if (xstat == "U" && ystat == "D") stat = "unmerged, deleted by them";
    else if (xstat == "U" && ystat == "A") stat = "unmerged, added by them";
    else if (xstat == "D" && ystat == "U") stat = "unmerged, deleted by us";
    else if (xstat == "A" && ystat == "A") stat = "unmerged, both added";
    else if (xstat == "U" && ystat == "U") stat = "unmerged, both modified";
    else if (xstat == "?" && ystat == "?") stat = "untracked";
    else if (xstat == "!" && ystat == "!") stat = "ignored";
    else stat = "unknown status";
    print f "   " stat;
}' | \
    column -t -s "  "
```

If you create an executable `git-status-ls` in a directory on your `PATH` (`$HOME/bin` should be a good place), you can type `git status-ls` in any Git repo. Or you could create a Git alias one-liner for this. You could also implement this using Perl, Python, C or whatever language you're most comfortable with.

---

Here's a sample output:

```
B                                renamed in index
A                                untracked
dont_delete_git_pre-commit_hook  untracked
```

---

Just realized, tabs are displaying as spaces. In the Awk script `print f "  " stat;` and in the `column -t -s " "` command, there is a tab (not spaces) between the double-quotes. You could use a separator other than tab.

---

Noticed an issue with the status flags handling in the above script and corrected it.

Comment: This won't show the "context" of unchanged files. But I guess I can start with this to add all other files too.

Comment: As is, this script will just tell you the status of what would/could be committed. It would seem listing unmodified tracked files will require a bit of work; I can't find a quick solution.

Answer (score 7):

### k

Directory listings for zsh with git features

https://github.com/supercrabtree/k

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I wanted something like this - something that would just annotate the regular `ls` output with the status from git. I quite liked the `k` command that was mentioned in a different answer, but it was zsh specific. So I wrote a bash script that can just sit in my library and be run from whatever shell I use, and which modifies the output from `ls` to add the extra information from git.

https://github.com/gerph/ls-with-git-status/

Since it modifies the output from `ls`, you can run it with any[1] of the `ls` switches and it will amend the output to include git information. It does not use quite the descriptions that were asked for in the question, but it does describe the changed state of files, and of repositories and submodules.

An example:

```
charles@laputa ~/projects/prm (add-ci-build-support)> lsg
Makefile                {ignored}
artifacts               {ignored}
build-to-junitxml.yaml  {untracked}
catalog
ci                      (replace-bash-junit-xml-processor↓4 19 forward) {1 modified}
ci-logs                 {ignored}
do-build.sh
index-makefile-ro.xsl
index-makefile.xsl
index.xml
index.xsl               {modified locally, 3 lines}
logs                    {ignored}
old-header              {untracked}
output                  {ignored}
project.config
src
test-results.xml        {untracked}
tmp                     {ignored}
```

In the above:

- There are a number of ignored files (the `{ignored}` appears in grey)
- There are some untracked (`{untracked}` appears in red)
- One file has had threee lines changed (`{modified locally, 3 lines}` appears in yellow, for modified)
- `{}` remarks are about files or directories.
- `()` remarks are about repositories.
- One directory, `ci` is a repository:

  - which is currently 4 commits behind the head of branch `replace-bash-junit-xml-processor` (the branch name is in cyan, the number of changes behind in blue)
  - which is 19 changes ahead of the point it was last committed at (`19 forward` is in yellow, for modified)
  - which contains 1 modified file (`1 modified` is in yellow, for modified)

Colouring is read from your git configuration used in `git status`.

[1] Some of the switches don't make sense - it forces 1-line-per-file, and doesn't support dired mode or some of the other formats.

Comment: Dude, you rock!

Answer (score -1):

This should get you started:

```
$ ( git ls-files -o|sed -e 's/$/ untracked/'; \
  git ls-files -m|sed -e 's/$/contents modified/') | 
  sort
```

See `git help ls-files` for other flags that you can use.

You might want to use your shell builtin `printf` to align the output the way you have it in your example:

```
$ (git ls-files -o|sed -e 's/$/ untracked/'; \
 git ls-files -m|sed -e 's/$/ contents modified/') |
    sort |
    while read file stat
    do
        printf "%-30s%-20s\n" $file $stat
    done
```

Comment: I fail to see how git ls-files can be used to report only on the directories content; i.e. don't show all the recursive information