# list files with git status

Tags: bash, git, ls

#### Background

I am well aware of how `git status` works, and even about `git ls-files`. Usually `git status` is all I need and want, it perfectly answers the question: "What is my status, and what files need my attention?"

However, I have been unable to find a quick command that answers the following question: "What files do I have, and what is their respective status?" So, I need a full listing of the directory (like `ls -la`) with a column that shows the status of each file/directory.

---

#### What I have tried

`git status -s --ignored` comes quite close to the output format that I want, but it just won't list the files that are unchanged between `HEAD`, index, and working directory. Also, it will recurse into directories.

`git ls-files` seems to be able to provide all the required info in scriptable form, but I've been unable to stop it from recursive listing the contents of all directories.

Obviously, I could hack something together that takes the output of these two commands and provides the view I would like to have. However, I would hate to reinvent the wheel if there is already some usable command out there.

---

#### Question

**Is there some way of listing all files in a directory with their respective git status?**
I want a full listing showing exactly the same files that `ls` would show.

---

#### Notes

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8727003/2445184) does not answer mine, because I definitely want an `ls` equivalent. Including unmodified, ignored, and untracked files, but excluding directory contents.

Comment: Consider using that other script but adding `-uall` to the `git status` options. It's not clear to me what you mean by "excluding directory contents" since `ls` looks at directory contents... You might also look at `git ls-files --other` output, and/or consider reading the directory/ies yourself, especially if you write a little Python program or similar. (Re-reading your question, I see you mean "don't recurse", really. So I think probably a Python program combining `os.listdir` and `git status --short` into whatever output format you want, would do nicely.)

Comment: [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) has several options which _may_ be suitable. Such as `git ls-files --directory <path/to/dir/>` which limits the output to files in a given directory (i.e. whichever path is defined in the `<path/to/dir/>` part) - if that's what you mean by _"stop it from recursive listing"_?. To list file status there is the `--[cached|deleted|others|ignored|stage|unmerged|killed|modified]` option. E.g. Running `git ls-files --modified <path/to/dir/>` will list files with a _modified_ status in  the  given`<path/to/dir/>` part.

Comment: @RobC The `git ls-files --directory` switch only stops it from listing the contents of ignored directories without tracked files in them. It will still recurse into all tracked directories and sub-[sub-...]directories. Which is complete overkill for what I want.

Comment: @RobC "recursive listing" = The command traverses the entire directory tree instead of pruning the subtrees whenever it finds a directory. `ls foo/` will print exactly the contents of that single directory, it will list that there is a directory `foo/bar/` contained therein, but **it will not recurse to list the contents of `foo/bar/`**. The `git` commands, however, will list all the `foo/bar/baz0001` ... `foo/bar/baz9999` files, one per line...

Comment: Cheers! @cmaster for the very informative explanation. I was aware of what _recursive listing_ means/does, however I didn't realize Git commands handled this differently - so TIL something new. Perhaps I should write more factually incorrect comments as a method of learning on SO instead of posting actual questions ;) So does git run something akin to `ls foo/**` instead?

Comment: @RobC Yes, exactly. Btw, writing factually incorrect answers is even more -- *educational* around here - I guess I've learned more from writing incorrect answers (and getting the feedback) than from actually reading other peoples answers ;-) It won't work if you do it on purpose, though...

Comment: Sure I get your point and thanks again. Yeah  I was kind of joking about _"should write more factually incorrect comments"_ and I understand that doing it (or answers) on purpose doesn't work. Anyway - hope you get a suitable answer/solution - _watching!_ ;) `</chat>`

Comment: This seems pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352494/one-git-command-to-show-status-of-all-files-in-a-directory although that doesn't have a good answer either. Also, I don't see what the difference is between this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727003/enhanced-ls-with-git-status-information?noredirect=1&lq=1. It seems like both are asking for a git command (or some other command) to show the status of all files in a directory. Could you clarify what the difference is?

Comment: It's amazing to me that in 2019 this is still so hard! I looked at the other questions, and the solutions are multi-page shell scripts handling `ls` args and colors and all kinds of fancy stuff. Is there really no simple way to use git commands to extract this info in a simple one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the paths Git inspects to just the current directory, use its Unix glob [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec)s. Since `git status` does a lot of checking against the index and against HEAD, use that, and to fill in the rest of the files `ls` would show you, use `ls`, just munge its output to have the same format as `git status`'s output and take only the ones `git status` didn't already list.

```
( git status -s -- ':(glob)*'; ls -A --file-type | awk '{print "   "$0}' ) \
| sort -t$'\n' -usk1.4
```

`:(glob)` tells Git the rest of the pathspec's a Unix glob, i.e. that `*` should match only one level, just like a (dotglob-enabled) shell wildcard¹.

The `-t$'\n'` tells `sort` that the field separator is a newline, i.e. it's all one big field, and `-usk1.4` says `u`niquify, only take the first of a run, `s`table, preserve input order where it doesn't violate sort key order (which is a little slower so you have to ask for that specifically), `k1.4` says the key starts at the first field, the fourth character in that field, with no end given so from there to the end.

---

<sup>¹ Why they decided to make pathspecs match neither like shell specs nor like gitignore specs by default, I might never bother learning, since I so much prefer ignorantly disapproving of their annoying choice.</sup>

Comment: Nice. I think, this is going to be the accepted answer because of the `':(glob)*'` hint. It's always nice to know how to tell a command what to do instead of working around what it does by default. I'm just waiting another day or two to see if the new bout of action inspires someone else to post an even better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because output of `git status -s` is enough, let's just make a bash routine around this function! Then for unchanged files we could *to echo* the proper signaling manually. Following the [specification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) we might use two symbols of space ' ' for this purpose either some another symbol. E.g. for directories, which are not tracked by Git anyway, selected symbol '_' as status code:

```
for FILE in *
do
  if [[ -f $FILE ]]
  then
    if ! [[ $(git status -s $FILE) ]]
    then
      # first two simbols below is a two-letter status code 
      echo "   $FILE"
    else 
      git status -s "$FILE"
    fi
  fi
  if [[ -d $FILE ]]
  then
    # first two symbols just selected as status code for directories
    echo "__ $FILE"
  fi
done
```

The script works in the same manner as `ls`. It can be written in one line using `;` as well.

Comment: That's indeed something to build upon. It's not yet ideal because a listing is not complete without the directories, imho. That can be added rather easily, though. Thanks.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I added directories into listing, using dummy status codes for them.